# Problems with Testing Jersey 3 Web Application using Jersey Test Framework

Tags: java, servlets, junit5, jersey-test-framework, jersey-3.0

I've got a Jersey 3 Web application (running on Tomcat10, JDK15 with JUnit5) in which I would like to Unit test my Endpoints.

Although, I have troubles setting these up. What I understand is, that I need to use a GrizzlyWebTestContainer in order to get the correct environment setup. Also, I figure I need somehow to pass my web.xml to the ServletcContainer. But how would I do this?

When I run the test, I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainer.getBaseUri()" because the return value of "org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.getTestContainer()" is null
```

So I need to configure somewhere a baseUri as well - but where? Unfortunately, I've found only examples and documentations with Grizzly**Test**ContainerFactory instead of GrizzlyWebTestC...
Could someone explain me what I did miss?

Any input is much appreciated!

This is my Unit test:

```
public class SimpleTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    public TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }


    @Override
    public DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        return ServletDeploymentContext
                .forServlet(new ServletContainer()) //how to pass web.xml here?
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(DatasetController.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Response response = target("/data/180").request().get(); //--> NPE is thrown here
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

This my Endpoint, I would like to test:

```
@Path("/data")
public class DataController {

    @Context ServletContext context;

    private DataSource ds;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { ds = (DataSource) context.getAttribute(DATASOURCE_CONTEXT_NAME); }

    @GET
    @Path("/{dataId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RolesAllowed({"1","2"})
    public Response getDataById(@PathParam("id") Long id) throws SQLException {
        logger.debug("Fetching dataset with id " + id);
        DSLContext create = DSL.using(ds.getConnection());

            //some JOOQ code

            return Response.ok(dto).build();
        }
}
```

This is the most important part in my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue causes because in org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest class you can find method with @Before annotation related to junit4

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
..
}
```

When you replace junit4 to junit5 this annotation do nothing and method doesn't invoke.

**Solution:**

```
public class YourJerseyTest extends JerseyTest {

@BeforeEach
void init() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
}
..
}
```